# VS17 не определяет библиотеку

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, pyttsx3

VS 17 не определяет библиотеку pysstx3. Я уже пробовал сделать установку библиотеки. Работаю в Python 3.6 т.к. в 3.7 нужная мне библиотека PyAudio не устанавливается.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
import sys
import webbrowser
import pysttx3

def talk (words):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say(words)
    engine.runAndWait()
talk ("Cпроси что-нибудь")
```

Comment: Лог ошибок покажите и как устанавливаете?

Comment: @Александр, нет логов. После запуска программы сразу ошибка на импортирование библиотеки «No module named 'pysttx3'». Возможно, в этой версии Python она как-то другим образом импортируется? Устанавливаю через «Окружение Python → Пакеты (PyPI)» в самом VS 17

Answer (score 0):

Я понял, при изменении окружения библиотек, нужно создавать новый проект.